Send notification of task assignments by email?(Django)
I am working on a kanban project. When a task is created, I want to send a notification mail to the employees assigned to the task. When a registration signal comes to my model, I capture it and get the assignees data from the information about the created task, but this data returns empty. When I check via Django Admin, the data seems to exist. When I check with Breakpoint, the data comes, but there is no data in the process I do with signal capture. In a little research, I learned that it may be caused by a problem such as assignees data not coming immediately, but I could not find anything about the solution. If anyone has any ideas, I am waiting, I shared sections of my code with you.
models.py
from django.db import models
from account.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from inupmt_be.utils import send_task_email

class Priority(models.TextChoices):
    LOW = 'low', 'Düşük'
    MEDIUM = 'medium', 'Orta'
    HIGH = 'hight', 'Yüksek'

class Column(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    priority = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Labels(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'

class Task(models.Model):
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='reported_tasks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assignees = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='assigned_tasks')
    column = models.ForeignKey(Column, related_name='tasks', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=128)
    labels = models.ManyToManyField(Labels, related_name='labels_task',blank=True)
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='comments_task',blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    priority = models.TextField(choices=Priority.choices)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    attachments = models.FileField(upload_to='attachments/', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.reporter} - {self.labels}'

@receiver(post_save, sender=Task)
def send_task_email_on_create_update(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        assigned_users_emails = instance.assignees.values_list('email', flat=True)
        send_task_email(
            task=instance,
            subject='New Task',
            message='New Task',
            recipient_list=list(assigned_users_emails)
        )
    else:
        assigned_users_emails = instance.assignees.values_list('email', flat=True)
        send_task_email(
            task=instance,
            subject='Update Task',
            message='Update Task',
            recipient_list=list(assigned_users_emails)
        )

class Comment(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name='task_comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.author} - {self.task}'


Since the signal method did not work, I wanted to try whether I could get the data with the save function in the task model, but I still could not reach a result, it was returning empty.
models.py with self function
from django.db import models
from account.models import User

class Priority(models.TextChoices):
    LOW = 'low', 'Düşük'
    MEDIUM = 'medium', 'Orta'
    HIGH = 'hight', 'Yüksek'

class Column(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    priority = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Labels(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'

class Task(models.Model):
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='reported_tasks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assignees = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='assigned_tasks')
    column = models.ForeignKey(Column, related_name='tasks', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=128)
    labels = models.ManyToManyField(Labels, related_name='labels_task',blank=True)
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='comments_task',blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    priority = models.TextField(choices=Priority.choices)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    attachments = models.FileField(upload_to='attachments/', blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk: 
            super().save(*args, **kwargs) 
            assignees_emails = [assignee.email for assignee in self.assignees.all()]
            print("Assignees e-mail addresses:", assignees_emails)
        else:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs) 

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.reporter} - {self.name}'

class Comment(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name='task_comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.author} - {self.task}'


